# Applet runs ok in NetBeans, but displays as gray box in browser

Tags: java, swing, browser, netbeans, applet

My applet runs perfectly in NetBeans, but displays as a gray box in browsers. I'm fairly certain it's the particular applet because other applets run just fine, and I get the same results on multiple computers. The java console does not show any problems and the stack ends with

```
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

How do I trouble shoot this problem?

Comment: Is the applet based on Swing or AWT components?  Is it available for us to visit?  What is the URL?

Comment: Swing. You can view it here: http://http://paullombardi.us/fb/  @AndrewThompson

Comment: I don't see any applet there.

Comment: That's the problem--it's displaying as a gray box in browsers and the java console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: No.  I should expand on 'see'.  My console is automatically configured to pop open on the JRE being invoked.  It is invoked for applets.  It did not pop up when I visited the page, and there was also no 'gray box' anywhere on the page.  Note I actually end up at http://www.http.com//paullombardi.us/fb/  Check the link as you posted it.

Comment: OK, for some reason my FF did not understand the `:` of the URL and got confused.  So, now I tried the applet in IE/FF/Chrome & the Applet Viewer & can confirm your strange result (perhaps no surprise there).  Is it Swing based?  Is all the GUI access done on the EDT?

Comment: I built the GUI with Swing components in NetBeans. The graph is from the JFreeChart library. The musical notation is PNG files on a JPanel. Here's a screenshot of it running in NetBeans: http://paullombardi.us/fb/fb.png

Comment: I do not know if all the GUI access is done on the EDT.

Comment: Check the EDT access.  The symptoms are not quite the same as other EDT problems, but it could be related.

Comment: I will look into this and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed everything from the applet except the form code, and unfortunately, it still loads as a blank box in browsers. I was not able to identify the problem. I built a new form in NetBeans, added my code little by little, and the new applet works perfectly.